# If $\beta = (172543)$, calculate $\beta^8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Please would someone check my answer?

My answer is $(124)(375).$  My method was to find $((\beta^2)^2)^2$.

Comment: It is correct, but you can have  the answer in a single step: the image of any element is the 8th element after (counted cyclically, of course).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You 're correct, but an easier way is to notice that $b$ is a 6-cycle, thus $b^6=1$ and thus $b^8=b^6b^2=b^2= (124)(375)$